# Existence of solutions (along subset of hypersurface) for a system of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, sg.symplectic-geometry

I had asked a [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404415/existence-of-solution-to-a-system-of-linear-pdes-with-boundary-conditions/404456#404456) about existence of solutions to a system of linear PDEs, and the answer made me realize that I needed to change things to try to make the construction work. So for the same construction, I now have the following system of 6 PDEs to solve, and I have certain "initial" or "boundary" conditions as before. Call the hypersurfaces $H_1 = \{r_1=0\}$ and $H_2 = \{-r_1^2 + r^2_2 = \epsilon\}$

The setting is $\mathbb{R}^4$ with polar coordinates $(r_1, \theta_1, r_2, \theta_2)$. I want to solve for (or show the existence of) functions  $\beta, \gamma, \alpha, \mu$,  on a subset of $\nu (H_1 \cap H_2)$, such that they satisfy the following:

\begin{align*}
2r_1\beta+(r_1^2 - 1)\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial r_1} + r_1\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \theta_1} &= r_1\\
(r_1^2 - 1)\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial r_2}+r_2\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta_1}&=0\\
(r_1^2-1)\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial \theta_2} + r_2^2\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial \theta_1} &= 0\\
r_2^2\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial r_1}+r_1\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial \theta_2}&=0\\
2\gamma r_2 + r_2^2\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial r_2} + r_2\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial \theta_2} &= r_2\\
r_1\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial r_2} - r_2\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial r_1} &=0
\end{align*}

As for "initial" or "boundary" conditions, I need $\beta = \gamma = 1$ and $\alpha = \mu = 0$ when $r_1 = \delta$, and $\beta = o(r_1)$ near $r_1 = 0$. A solution is not expected to exist all over $H_1 \cap H_2$, but I want to see if solutions can be found that are defined for some values of $\theta_2$ along $r_1 = 0$.

I am not able to work out a general form for the solutions as was suggested in the answer to the previous question, possibly because all the functions $\beta, \gamma, \alpha, \mu$ and their partials are now "coupled".

Comment: Here's a hint:  Set $\bar\alpha = r_1\,\alpha$, $\bar\beta = ({r_1}^2-1)(\beta-\tfrac12)$, $\bar\mu = r_2\,\mu$, and $\bar\gamma = {r_2}^2(\gamma-\tfrac12)$ and consider the equations that you get for $\bar\alpha$, $\bar\beta$, $\bar\mu$, and $\bar\gamma$.

Comment: Also, are you *sure* that you have the signs right?  For example, if one flipped the signs of $\beta$ and $\gamma$, all the equations for the barred quantities would be differences of partials *except* for the third equation, which would still be a sum.  If the equations *were* all differences, then the general solution would be easy to write down, and the solution would have geometric significance, but with the flipped sign, the system looks very contrived.

Comment: The equations come from here: let $V = \beta (r_1-\frac{1}{r_1}) \partial_{r_1} + \gamma r_2 \partial_{r_2} + \alpha \partial_{\theta_1} + \mu \partial_{\theta_2}$, and $\omega = r_1 d r_1 d\theta_1 + r_2 d r_2 d\theta_2$. When is $\mathcal{L}_{V}\omega = \omega$? I checked a few times, I think the signs are correct. The idea is: try and extend the (Liouville) vector field $V_1 = (r_1-\frac{1}{r_1}) \partial_{r_1} + r_2 \partial_{r_2}$ over some points in $H_1 \cap H_2$. I don't know if the solution should have any geometric significance at all, and $V$ is indeed just a guess. It may not work.

Comment: As it turns out, it doesn't seem to work. The general solution for $\beta$ looks like $\beta$ = $\frac{1}{r_1^2-1}(\frac{r_1^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\partial H + \partial F + \partial G}{\partial \theta_1})$, where $H$ is a function of $r_1$ and $\theta_1$, $F$ of $\theta_2$ and $\theta_1$, and $G$ of $r_2$ and $\theta_1$. Near $r_1 = 0$, for $\beta$ to be $o(r_1)$, $ \frac{\partial H + \partial F + \partial G}{\partial \theta_1}$ must be independent of $\theta_1$, but since the functions must be periodic restricted to $\theta_1$, no solution exists anywhere for all values of $\theta_1$.